# Why Format-Table omits properties

Tags: powershell

The properties returned by `Get-NetIPAddress` are different from those from `Get-NetIPAddress | Format-Table`.

I understand from Format-Table manual that by default a property will not be printed if not all object have it, but I have e.g. InterfaceAlias on all interfaces and also plenty of empty terminal width. So how does Format-Table choose what to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how does Format-Table choose what to display?

The NetTCPIP module ships with a custom formatting file which is loaded as soon as the module is imported, and these contain custom view definitions for different data types.

When to apply which view definition from these formatting files depend on the *type* of the object that's being formatted.

In your case, `Get-NetIPAddress` returns CIM instances of class `ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress`, so upon receiving the first object via the pipeline, `Format-Table` resolves the type name to a custom view definition (if present), and that determines the properties (both real and calculated) you're shown in the resulting table view.

You can discover formatting data with the `Get-FormatData` cmdlet:

```
$outputType = Get-Command Get-NetIPAddress |Select -Expand OutputType -Last 1
Get-FormatData -TypeName $outputType.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I want to see all the properties I usually do something like:

```
get-netipaddress | fl *
```

You can also do:

```
get-netipaddresi | ft *
```

To avoid the format file.